# padding jump in bxslider jquery css

Tags: jquery, css, slider, padding

I have got a little problem.
I got a bxslider running on a website i am making. everything works properly until the slider starts at start again. It contains 3 slides, so after 2 clicks i am at slide 3. Once i click again on the "next button" it goes to slide 1. that is correct allthough it shifts up 30 pixels. I guess this is because i set my UL to padding-top to 30px. This is strange since i tell the whole UL to have a top padding.

I hope that someone can help me, it already took me over 2 hours to fix.
the website we are talking about: http://welkommagazine.nl/luuk/

thanks in advance.
Luuk

Comment: I checked in FF 3.6, it is working fine. Are you facing this issue in any specific browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried moving the padding onto the parent div?

Comment: yes i did, but then the UL starts lower (30px), so the slide disappears earlier if you catch my drift. it needs to disappear at header edge

Comment: Changing the padding-top on the ul to margin-top fixes it in Firefox, not tested in any others.

Comment: wow, how stupid of me, you are right! i thought the margin would cause the same problem as your other solution, so i didnt even bother to try. thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: thanks, this issue was killing me as well.  I had to set padding:0 and margin:0 on my slide show ul.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the padding and margin to 0 on the slider ul worked for me.

```
#slider {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```